# Uninstall MirrorGo Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, uninstallation

I installed the MirrorGo (Stream & Recorder) app from the Play Store to try but uninstalled it over privacy concerns in my Android 10. Everything looks fine, but recently I discovered it still left some traces in the device. When I checked the virtual keyboards in Language & input settings, I found the MirrorGo keyboard is still available.

[image]

I tried checking the list of all apps on the mobile and couldn't find anything related to that. How do I remove that from my device?

Device: Pixel 3;
Android Version: 10 / Android Q;
Device status: Unrooted;

Comment: Can you setup [tag:adb], then run the command `adb shell dumpsys input_method > input_method.txt` and upload the content of the file input_method.txt in the question (by [edit]ing it)?

Comment: I reset the mobile now which resolved the issue in the hardway. BTW thank you Firelord.

Answer (score 0):

Long click on the keyboard, and it shall show an option to remove the keyboard. In your Apps section in settings, there should be apps like MirrorGo Connector, which you can simply uninstall. However, for a full clean you shall require root.

Comment: I tried long click option but it not giving any options and also I checked list of all apps in the device but none related to MirrorGo app.

Comment: Any app starting with Wondershare or ending with the name Connector? Those could be possible culprits. Also Wondershare has the upper edge if it used USB debugging. Just in case, you should turn off USB debugging and revoke authorization if it is turned on.

Comment: Yeah I gone through every app. Nothing related to Wondershare. I did give USB debugging permissions at the time I tried the app. I just reset the mobile now. BTW Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called "connector". It has the same icon that mirrorgo keyboard has. You can find it in the apps settings and uninstall it. It makes mirrorgo keyboard disappear.